# Why is my new Google Maps API key not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I have a function that works with google api which has been working for years. We had to get a new api key and now nothing seems to work.
What happens is that I dont get any output after the   alert( address) line as the code from   geocoder.geocode doesnt work. There is no error as the geocoder.geocode code just fails to work and it skips down to the last alert .

```
//in view to call the function
    <input type="button" value="calculate" id="calculate_address_lat_long" class="btn btn-info btn-block waves-effect waves-light">
     <div class="mute" id="formated_address_lat_long"></div> 

    //in layout          <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=hidden" type="text/javascript"></script>




  $(document).on('click', '#calculate_address_lat_long', function () {
        var address = '';
        address += $('#street').val();
        address += ' ' + $('#suburb').val();
        address += ' ' + $('#postcode').val();
        address += ' ' + $('#state').val();

     //  alert( $('#street').val());


              alert(google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK);
            alert( address);
     //geocoder function fails to run with no error      
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {


                  alert('asdasd');
                  console.log(results); 
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                $('#lat').val(latitude);
                $('#long').val(longitude);
                $('#formated_address_lat_long')
                    .html('<div class="alert alert-success">' + results[0].formatted_address + '</div>')
                    .fadeTo(100, 0.1).fadeTo(250, 1)
                    .css({"position": "relative","top": "15px"});
           // alert($('#lat').val(latitude));

            } else {
                  alert('qqqasdasd');

             //     alert($('#lat').val(latitude));
           // alert($('#long').val(longitude));
                $('#formated_address_lat_long')
                    .fadeTo(100, 0.1).fadeTo(250, 1)
                    .html('<div class="alert alert-error">Address Not Found</div>')
                    .css({"position": "relative","top": "15px"});
            }
        });
         alert('1111qqqasdasd');

    });
```

Comment: Your question doesn't seem related to CakePHP. Please update your question with respective details if you think there's something that is specifically related.

Comment: It is js code in a cakephp project . I am not sure what you are asking as apart from the button code in theview no more code exists. Surely the question makes sense as is though

Comment: *Surely the question makes sense as is though* - no, because nobody can reproduce that. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: all the code for this api key has been given. its not a code issue as the api key was not activated. This fact probably should have been picked up as the code interacts with gcc

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved from the google console end. Not only do you create a api key for google maps but a little known fact is that you must activate/enable to api key for js and for geolocation in the google cloud console under google maps. There is nothing wrong with the code given which was everything to do with the api key, , and it all works fine now